# Create complex object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qm5i.png)

When I submit how to get all checkbox states and notes using useState in hooks

```js
function handleEditformsubmit(e: any) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var errids = []

  var arr_length = InspectionList.length
  var chkbx = 'chkbx_'
  var notes = 'notes_'
  var data = []

  for (var i = 1; i <= arr_length; i++) {
    let chkbx_state: any = (
      document.getElementById(chkbx + i) as HTMLInputElement
    ).checked
    let user_note: any = (
      document.getElementById(notes + i) as HTMLInputElement
    )?.value
    if (!chkbx_state && !user_note) {
      document.getElementById(notes + i)
      console.log(notes + i)
      errids.push(notes + i)
      setErrId(errids)
    }
    let row_data = Object()
    row_data['id'] = i
    row_data['is_checked'] = chkbx_state
    row_data['notes'] = user_note
    data.push(row_data)
  }
  setInsData(data)
  errids = []
}
```

This is working fine, but I would like to learn how to solve using states.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
  const [inspectionList, setInspectionList] = useState([
    // Initialize your InspectionList here
    // Example: { id: 1, isChecked: false, notes: '' },
    // Add similar objects for each item in your list
  ]);

  const [errIds, setErrIds] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (id) => {
    const updatedList = inspectionList.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, isChecked: !item.isChecked } : item
    );
    setInspectionList(updatedList);
  };

  const handleNoteChange = (id, value) => {
    const updatedList = inspectionList.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, notes: value } : item
    );
    setInspectionList(updatedList);
  };

  const handleEditFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errIds = [];

    for (const item of inspectionList) {
      if (!item.isChecked && !item.notes) {
        errIds.push(item.id);
      }
    }

    setErrIds(errIds);

    // You can also set the updated inspection data here
    // setInsData(inspectionList);

    // Clear errIds
    setErrIds([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleEditFormSubmit}>
        {inspectionList.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={item.isChecked}
              onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(item.id)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              value={item.notes}
              onChange={(e) => handleNoteChange(item.id, e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {errIds.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          Errors: {errIds.map((id) => <span key={id}>{id}, </span>)}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

In this code:

We maintain the state of your inspection list using useState.
We use handleCheckboxChange and handleNoteChange functions to update the state when a checkbox or note input changes.
In handleEditFormSubmit, we iterate over the list to check for errors, and we set errIds accordingly.
Finally, we use the state variables to display the checkboxes, notes, and error messages in the component's JSX.

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const arr = [
  {
     id: 1,
     name: "John Doe",
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     name: "Mark A",
  },
  {
     id: 3,
     name: "Triple H",
  },
];


const CheckBoxSelect = () => {
const [errIds, setErrIds] = useState([]);
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

const handleCheckBox = () => {
  setIsChecked(!isChecked);
};

const handleIndex = (id) => {
   if (errIds?.includes(id)) {
      setErrIds((prevNum) => prevNum.filter((num) => num !== id));
    }  else {
       setErrIds((prev) => [...prev, id]);
    }
  };

console.log("Stored Data: ", errIds);


 return (


 <div>
  {arr &&
    arr.map((i) => (
      <div key={i.id}>
        <div>
          <input
            onChange={() => handleCheckBox(i.id)}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={errIds.includes(i.id) ? true : false}
            id="checkbox"
          />
          <label
            onClick={() => handleIndex(i.id)}
            htmlFor="checkbox"
          ></label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>{i.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
 );
};

export default CheckBoxSelect;
```